# How to test beta and alpha simultaneously on google play

Tags: android, google-play

I'm having difficulty finding information on how to test simultaneously on Alpha and Beta within the Google Play store. I have recently moved from Alpha to Beta with the goal of having the test environment separate from the development environment. The problem that I'm running into, is how do I, as the developer, exclude myself from the Beta so that I can run/download the Alpha build on my devices?

Answer (score 5):

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

> Please keep in mind that if a user is eligible for both alpha and beta
>   versions, they’ll receive the alpha version.